# count the atomic elements in a deep list in prolog

Tags: prolog

```
elem([],0).

elem([H|T],R):-atomic(H),elem(T,R1),R1 is R+1.

elem([H|T],R):-elem(H,R1),elem(T,R2),R is R1+R2.
```

This is my code and after I searched the answer to my problem on this site, I didn't find a good one. The error is : `?- elem([1,[2],3,4],R)`.

```
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated.
```

but it should be **R = 3**.

Comment: Did you try tracing the execution? Type `trace.` at the Prolog prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the second line, you should have

```
R is R1 + 1
```

instead of

```
R1 is R + 1.
```

Comment: Reason for this: R is the result for [H|T], R1 is the result for T only. Therefore, if H is atomic, R will be 1 + whatever results from applying the predicate to the tail of the list (T).

Comment: Thank you but the output is R=4 when it should be R=3. I tried to modify it to elem([H|T],R):-atomic(H),!,elem(T,R1),R is R1+1. but its still no good, it counts [2] as atomic when it shouldn't.

Comment: I understand now. You only want it to count on the top level. Write the third clause like this (i.e., remove the recursion on the head, when the head is not atomic):

elem([H|T], R) :- elem(T, R).

Comment: You are welcome. Just one more thing to clarify: you said earlier that it counted "[2]" as atomic. This statement is slightly incorrect. What it actually did was counting "2" as atomic, by going one level deeper in the list.